# resolve loading USE or USELSX error from script

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

i'm working with lotus notes 6.5.6 and sometimes, when users try to exegute an agent notes retrive "loading USE or USELSX module" error so, i have to go into the library that is used my that agent and re-save it. After that the agent work. I don't know the cause of this error but i'm studying for understand it, meantime i have to find a solution that allow users to solve the problem without my presence.
So i'm look for a solution that allow users to access the library and resave it to solve that error.

I try to do this:

```
Dim db As NotesDatabase
Dim session As New NotesSession
Dim doclib As NotesDocument
Dim colllib As NotesNoteCollection
Dim id As String
Set db=session.CurrentDatabase
Set colllib = db.CreateNoteCollection(False)
colllib.SelectScriptLibraries=True
Call colllib.BuildCollection()
Id=colllib.GetFirstNoteId
While Not Id=""     
    Set doclib=db.GetDocumentByID(Id)
    If Not doclib Is Nothing Then
        Call doclib.ComputeWithForm(False,False)
        Call doclib.Save(True,False)
    End If
    id=colllib.GetNextNoteId(Id)
Wend
```

but the error is not resolved.
How can i do ?
thank's

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to resolve your issue you would need to recompile the script (what is automatically done when saving it in the Designer- Client) and then programmatically sign it (what is only possible using the C-API). Calling a "ComputeWithForm" on a Design- Element does NOT recompile the script.

Rather than fixing something that should not be broken, I would rather investigate why this agent stops running.

Usually this happens, when the designer- task "merges" script- libraries / agents from different templates to one database.

I am quite sure, that the reason for your agent not working anymore is the nightly designer task. Try to take out the template- name from the "broken" database or manipulate it (add an "x" or something) so that you keep the information, but designer task does not find the corresponding template. This should fix your problem.

If you really cannot fix the problem with this approach, then try this code I found [here](http://www.nsftools.com/tips/LSRecompile.lss), put it in an agent and let the user call it via another agent with ag.RunOnServer (then it runs with more rights than the user has):

```vb
'LS Recompile: 

Option Public
Option Explicit

%REM
An example of using Notes API calls to recompile LotusScript.

version 1.0
Julian Robichaux
http://www.nsftools.com
%END REM


'** Notes C-API functions
Declare Function OSPathNetConstruct Lib "nnotes.dll" (Byval portName As Integer, _
Byval serverName As String, Byval fileName As String, Byval pathName As String) As Integer

Declare Function NSFDbOpen Lib "nnotes.dll" (Byval dbName As String, hDb As Long) As Integer
Declare Function NSFDbClose Lib "nnotes.dll" (Byval hDb As Long) As Integer

Declare Function NSFNoteLSCompile Lib "nnotes.dll" (Byval hDb As Long, _
Byval hNote As Long, Byval dwFlags As Long) As Integer
Declare Function NSFNoteSign Lib "nnotes.dll" (Byval hNote As Long) As Integer
Declare Function NSFNoteUpdate Lib "nnotes.dll" (Byval hNote As Long, _
Byval flags As Integer) As Integer

Declare Function OSLoadString Lib "nnotes.dll" (Byval hModule As Long, Byval stringCode As Integer, _
Byval retBuffer As String, Byval bufferLength As Integer) As Integer


'================================================================
' Base class for working with Notes databases at the API level
'================================================================
Class APIBaseClass
    Private db As NotesDatabase
    Private hDb As Long
    Private lastError As String


    Public Sub New ()
        '** nothing to instantiate in the base class
    End Sub


    Public Sub Delete ()
        Call CloseDatabase()
    End Sub


    Public Function OpenDatabase (db As NotesDatabase) As Integer
        On Error Goto processError

        If (hDb > 0) Then
            Call CloseDatabase()
        End If

        '** reset the internals
        Set Me.db = db
        lastError = ""

        Dim pathName As String*256
        Dim result As Integer

        '** create a proper network path name with OSPathNetConstruct
        Call OSPathNetConstruct(0, db.Server, db.FilePath, pathName)

        '** open the database and get a handle with NSFDbOpen
        result = NSFDbOpen(pathName, hDb)
        If result = 0 Then
            OpenDatabase = True
        Else
            Call SetLastError("Cannot open database " & db.FilePath & " on server " & db.Server, result)
        End If

        Exit Function

processError:
        Call SetLastError("Error opening database", 0)
        Exit Function

    End Function


    Public Sub CloseDatabase ()
        On Error Resume Next

        If (hDb > 0) Then
            Call NSFDbClose(hDb)
        End If

        Set db = Nothing
        hDb = 0
        lastError = ""
    End Sub


    Private Function SetLastError (errText As String, apiResultCode As Integer) As String
        If (apiResultCode <> 0) Then
            LastError = "API Error " & apiResultCode & ": " & GetAPIError(apiResultCode)
        Elseif (Err > 0) Then
            LastError = "Notes Error " & Err & ": " & Error$
        Else
            LastError = ""
        End If

        If (Len(errText) > 0) Then
            LastError = errText & ". " & LastError
        End If
    End Function


    Public Function GetLastError () As String
        GetLastError = LastError
    End Function


    Public Function GetAPIError (errorCode As Integer) As String
        Dim errorString As String*256
        Dim returnErrorString As String
        Dim resultStringLength As Long
        Dim errorCodeTranslated As Integer

        Const ERR_MASK = &H3fff
        Const PKG_MASK = &H3f00
        Const ERRNUM_MASK = &H00ff

        '** mask off the top 2 bits of the errorCode that was returned; this is
        '** what the ERR macro in the API does
        errorCodeTranslated = (errorCode And ERR_MASK)

        '** get the error code translation using the OSLoadString API function
        resultStringLength = OSLoadString(0, errorCodeTranslated, errorString, Len(errorString) - 1)

        '** strip off the null-termination on the string before you return it
        If (Instr(errorString, Chr(0)) > 0) Then
            returnErrorString = Left$(errorString, Instr(errorString, Chr(0)) - 1)
        Else
            returnErrorString = errorString
        End If

        GetAPIError = returnErrorString

    End Function

End Class


'================================================================
' Special subclass for recompiling a note/doc in a database
'================================================================
Class LotusScriptRecompiler As APIBaseClass

    Public Function RecompileLSByNoteID (noteID As String) As Integer
        On Error Goto processError

        If (db Is Nothing) Then
            Call SetLastError("Database is not open", 0)
            Exit Function
        End If

        Dim doc As NotesDocument
        Set doc = db.GetDocumentByID(noteID)
        RecompileLSByNoteID = RecompileLS(doc)
        Exit Function

processError:
        Call SetLastError("Error recompiling LotusScript for " & noteID, 0)
        Exit Function

    End Function


    Public Function RecompileLSByUNID (unid As String) As Integer
        On Error Goto processError

        If (db Is Nothing) Then
            Call SetLastError("Database is not open", 0)
            Exit Function
        End If

        Dim doc As NotesDocument
        Set doc = db.GetDocumentByUNID(unid)
        RecompileLSByUNID = RecompileLS(doc)
        Exit Function

processError:
        Call SetLastError("Error recompiling LotusScript for " & unid, 0)
        Exit Function

    End Function


    Public Function RecompileLS (doc As NotesDocument) As Integer
        On Error Goto processError

        Dim hNote As Long
        Dim unid As String
        Dim result As Integer

        If (hDb = 0) Then
            Call SetLastError("Database is not open", 0)
            Exit Function
        Elseif (doc Is Nothing) Then
            Call SetLastError("Invalid document reference", 0)
            Exit Function
        End If

        '** super-special-secret way of getting an API handle to a NotesDocument
        hNote = doc.Handle
        unid = doc.UniversalID

        '** first, we compile the note
        result = NSFNoteLSCompile(hDb, hNote, 0)
        If (result <> 0) Then
            Call SetLastError("Cannot compile LotusScript for " & GetTitle(doc), result)
            Exit Function
        End If

        '** then we sign it
        result = NSFNoteSign(hNote)
        If (result <> 0) Then
            Call SetLastError("Cannot sign " & GetTitle(doc), result)
            Exit Function
        End If

        '** then we save it
        result = NSFNoteUpdate(hNote, 0)
        If (result <> 0) Then
            Call SetLastError("Cannot save " & GetTitle(doc), result)
            Exit Function
        End If

        '** update the in-memory reference to the object
        Delete doc
        Set doc = db.GetDocumentByUNID(unid)

        '** a little trick to avoid this message on recompiled forms:
        '** This document has been altered since the last time it was signed! Intentional tampering may have occurred.
        Call doc.Sign()
        Call doc.Save(True, False)

        lastError = ""
        RecompileLS = True
        Exit Function

processError:
        Call SetLastError("Error recompiling LotusScript for " & GetTitle(doc), 0)
        Exit Function

    End Function


    Public Function GetTitle (doc As NotesDocument) As String
        On Error Resume Next
        If (doc Is Nothing) Then
            Exit Function
        End If

        Dim title As String
        title = doc.~$Title(0)
        If (Instr(title, "|") > 0) Then
            title = Strleft(title, "|")
        End If

        If (title = "") Then
            title = "(untitled)"
        End If

        GetTitle = |"| & title & |"|
    End Function
End Class



Sub Initialize
    '** As a test, let's recompile all the agents, script libraries, and forms
    '** in this database
    Dim session As New NotesSession
    Dim db As NotesDatabase
    Dim nc As NotesNoteCollection
    Dim recompiler As New LotusScriptRecompiler
    Dim noteID As String

    '** create our recompiler object
    Set db = session.CurrentDatabase
    Call recompiler.OpenDatabase(db)
    If (recompiler.GetLastError <> "") Then
        Print recompiler.GetLastError
        Exit Sub
    End If

    '** compile the script libraries first (note that this will NOT build a
    '** dependency tree -- rather, we'll try to brute-force around the 
    '** dependencies by recompiling until either (A) there are no errors,
    '** or (B) the number of errors we get is the same as we got last time)
    Dim errCount As Integer, lastCount As Integer
    Set nc = db.CreateNoteCollection(False)
    nc.SelectScriptLibraries = True
    Call nc.BuildCollection

    Print "SCRIPT LIBRARIES"
    Do
        lastCount = errCount
        errCount = 0

        noteID = nc.GetFirstNoteId
        Do Until (noteID = "")
            If recompiler.RecompileLSByNoteID(noteID) Then
                Print "Successfully recompiled " & _
                recompiler.GetTitle(db.GetDocumentByID(noteID))
            Else
                Print recompiler.GetLastError
                errCount = errCount + 1
            End If

            noteID = nc.GetNextNoteId(noteID)
        Loop
    Loop Until ( (errCount = 0) Or (errCount = lastCount) )

    '** then compile everything else
    Set nc = db.CreateNoteCollection(False)
    nc.SelectAgents = True
    nc.SelectForms = True
    Call nc.BuildCollection

    Print "FORMS AND AGENTS"
    noteID = nc.GetFirstNoteId
    Do Until (noteID = "")
        If recompiler.RecompileLSByNoteID(noteID) Then
            Print "Successfully recompiled " & _
            recompiler.GetTitle(db.GetDocumentByID(noteID))
        Else
            Print recompiler.GetLastError
        End If

        noteID = nc.GetNextNoteId(noteID)
    Loop

    Call recompiler.CloseDatabase()
    Print "All done"
End Sub
```